# What does FETCO2(end-tidal fraction CO2 concentration) represent?

Tags: breathing

What is end-tidal fractional CO2 concentration? I have searched online and found little actually explaining what this measurement is. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're asking about the [procedure](https://www.medicinenet.com/what_is_end-tidal_capnography/article.htm) or the underlying concepts of CO2 concentration or how a [capnometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capnometry) works.  But in brief, it is measured at the end of an exhaled breath, which is least 'contaminated' by inhaled but unused air from the conduction zone (trachea, etc.).  The measurement is done by looking at the blockage of light from an infrared light to a sensor by the CO2 - exactly the same mechanism by which global warming works.  And the way it's reported is, in this case, as a fraction from 0 to 1.  It could be reported as a percentage by multiplying by 100, or as a partial pressure by multiplying by the total atmospheric pressure (often 760 torr at sea level).